# How to specify boto3 data file when using boto3.resouce in py2exe?

Tags: python-3.x, py2exe, boto3

### Environment

OS: Windows7

Python: 3.4 (using virtualenv)

### Question

Well, I build a python file using boto3 to get running instance from AWS and works fine.

That's my code:

```
import boto3
from tabulate import tabulate

result = []
for instance in boto3.resource('ec2', region_name='sa-east-1').instances.filter(
        Filters=[{'Name': 'instance-state-name', 'Values': ['running']}, {'Name': 'tag:Name', 'Values': ['<my_modules>*']},
                 {'Name': 'tag:Ambiente', 'Values': ['producao', 'Producao']}]):
    result += [[instance.tags[next(idx for (idx, d) in enumerate(instance.tags) if d['Key'] == 'Name')]['Value'],
                instance.private_ip_address,
                instance.tags[next(idx for (idx, d) in enumerate(instance.tags) if d['Key'] == 'Ambiente')]['Value']]]
print(tabulate(sorted(result)))
```

Now, I want to make a exe from that and for this, I'm using Py2exe...

I copy *.json from <.virtual_env>\Lib\site-package\botocore\data and all content of <.virtual_env>\Lib\site-package\botocore\data\s3 to \data

This is my setup.py file:

```
from distutils.core import setup
from tabulate import tabulate
import os
import py2exe

dir_base = 'data'
aws_data_files = [(dir_base, [os.path.join(dir_base, 'endpoints.json'), os.path.join(dir_base, '_retry.json'),
                              os.path.join(dir_base, 'cacert.pem')])]
s3_module = 's3'
s3_dates = ['2006-03-01']
s3_files = ['paginators-1.json', 'service-2.json', 'waiters-2.json']
for dir_date in s3_dates:
    list_files = []
    for file in s3_files:
        list_files.append(os.path.join(dir_base, s3_module, dir_date, file))
    aws_data_files.append((os.path.join(dir_base, s3_module, dir_date), list_files))

print(tabulate(aws_data_files))

setup(
    options={
        'py2exe': {
            'optimize': 0,
            'packages': ['boto3', 'html']}},
    console=['<my_python_file>.py'],
    # package_data={'boto3', aws_data_files},
    data_files=aws_data_files)
```

The setup.py result is:

```
python setup.py py2exe
------------------  ---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
data                ['data\\endpoints.json', 'data\\_retry.json', 'data\\cacert.pem']
data\s3\2006-03-01  ['data\\s3\\2006-03-01\\paginators-1.json', 'data\\s3\\2006-03-01\\service-2.json', 'data\\s3\\2006-03-01\\waiters-2.json']
------------------  ---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
running py2exe

  25 missing Modules
  ------------------
? Cookie                              imported from botocore.vendored.requests.compat
? OpenSSL                             imported from botocore.vendored.requests.packages.urllib3.contrib.pyopenssl
? Queue                               imported from botocore.vendored.requests.packages.urllib3.connectionpool
? _abcoll                             imported from botocore.vendored.requests.packages.urllib3.packages.ordered_dict
? backports                           imported from botocore.vendored.requests.packages.urllib3.packages.ssl_match_hostname
? certifi                             imported from botocore.vendored.requests.certs
? cookielib                           imported from botocore.vendored.requests.compat
? distutils.filelist                  imported from distutils.util
? distutils.text_file                 imported from distutils.extension, distutils.sysconfig
? distutils.versionpredicate          imported from distutils.dist
? email.Utils                         imported from botocore.compat
? multiprocessing.SimpleQueue         imported from concurrent.futures.process
? ndg                                 imported from botocore.vendored.requests.packages.urllib3.contrib.pyopenssl
? ordereddict                         imported from botocore.compat
? pyasn1                              imported from botocore.vendored.requests.packages.urllib3.contrib.pyopenssl
? readline                            imported from cmd, code, pdb
? simplejson                          imported from botocore.compat, botocore.vendored.requests.compat
? urllib.getproxies                   imported from botocore.vendored.requests.compat
? urllib.proxy_bypass                 imported from botocore.vendored.requests.compat
? urllib.quote                        imported from botocore.compat, botocore.vendored.requests.compat
? urllib.quote_plus                   imported from botocore.vendored.requests.compat
? urllib.unquote                      imported from botocore.compat, botocore.vendored.requests.compat
? urllib.unquote_plus                 imported from botocore.compat, botocore.vendored.requests.compat
? urllib.urlencode                    imported from botocore.compat, botocore.vendored.requests.compat, botocore.vendored.requests.packages.urllib3.request
? wcwidth                             imported from tabulate
Building 'dist\listar-maquinas-camada8.exe'.
Building shared code archive 'dist\library.zip'.
Copy c:\windows\system32\python34.dll to dist
Copy c:\python34x86\DLLs\unicodedata.pyd to dist\unicodedata.pyd
Copy c:\python34x86\DLLs\_ssl.pyd to dist\_ssl.pyd
Copy c:\python34x86\DLLs\_socket.pyd to dist\_socket.pyd
Copy c:\python34x86\DLLs\_decimal.pyd to dist\_decimal.pyd
Copy C:\Python\Envs\nimbos-business-core\lib\site-packages\win32\win32wnet.pyd to dist\win32wnet.pyd
Copy c:\python34x86\DLLs\_elementtree.pyd to dist\_elementtree.pyd
Copy c:\python34x86\DLLs\pyexpat.pyd to dist\pyexpat.pyd
Copy C:\Python\Envs\nimbos-business-core\lib\site-packages\win32\_win32sysloader.pyd to dist\_win32sysloader.pyd
Copy c:\python34x86\DLLs\select.pyd to dist\select.pyd
Copy c:\python34x86\DLLs\_bz2.pyd to dist\_bz2.pyd
Copy C:\Python\Envs\nimbos-business-core\lib\site-packages\win32\win32api.pyd to dist\win32api.pyd
Copy c:\python34x86\DLLs\_lzma.pyd to dist\_lzma.pyd
Copy c:\python34x86\DLLs\_hashlib.pyd to dist\_hashlib.pyd
Copy c:\python34x86\DLLs\_ctypes.pyd to dist\_ctypes.pyd
Copy c:\python34x86\DLLs\_multiprocessing.pyd to dist\_multiprocessing.pyd
Copy ExtensionDLL C:\Python\Envs\nimbos-business-core\lib\site-packages\pypiwin32_system32\pywintypes34.dll to dist\
```

But when I try to execute the generated exe file, i received this:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Python\Envs\nimbos-business-core\lib\site-packages\boto3\session.py", line 341, in resource
    service_name, 'resources-1', api_version)
  File "C:\Python\Envs\nimbos-business-core\lib\site-packages\botocore\loaders.py", line 132, in _wrapper
    data = func(self, *args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Python\Envs\nimbos-business-core\lib\site-packages\botocore\loaders.py", line 378, in load_service_model
    known_service_names=', '.join(sorted(known_services)))
botocore.exceptions.UnknownServiceError: Unknown service: 'ec2'. Valid service names are:

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "listar-maquinas-camada8.py", line 5, in <module>
  File "C:\Python\Envs\nimbos-business-core\lib\site-packages\boto3\__init__.py", line 92, in resource
    return _get_default_session().resource(*args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Python\Envs\nimbos-business-core\lib\site-packages\boto3\session.py", line 347, in resource
    has_low_level_client)
boto3.exceptions.ResourceNotExistsError: The 'ec2' resource does not exist.
The available resources are:
   -
```

Comment: does it work without being packaged? do you need to import the boto pip package into the exe somehow, are you running it on a different machine?

Comment: same machine. Without being packaged you mean withou transform to exe? If this is the case, yes. I think the boto3 doesn't finding the data files in the package, I need somehow said to boto3 where to find the files